# error when running application

Tags: ios, iphone, nsrunningapplication

i get this answer when I'm trying to run my application both on my iphone and in simulator.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: and i have been checked so the appDelegate.m are in the Compile Sources

Comment: That's a link error, not a runtime error.  It means you haven't linked-in the `AppDelegate` implementation file.

Comment: YAAY! fixed, i forgotted implementation in appdelegate